# Almacenar suma de cada fila de una matriz en un vector en C# forms

Tags: c#, array, formularios

tengo una tarea que debo terminar y esta es la única parte que me falta del programa, la cual me dice que debo realizar la impresión de la matriz y aparte debo sacar la suma de cada uno de los renglones y esa sumatoria de cada uno de los renglones debe almacenarse en un vector, ademas de que debe imprimirse

Este es mi código:
Como puede verse R es para renglones y C para las columnas. Sola me faltaría hacer la suma de cada renglón y almacenarlo en un vector. Agradecería mucho de su ayuda.

```
        int R, C;
        int[,] N;
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        N= new int [4,5];

        for (R=0;R <4; R++)
        {
            for (C=0; C<5;C++)
            {
                N[R, C] = aleatorio.Next(-100, 100);
                txtMatriz.Text = txtMatriz.Text + N[R, C] + "\t";

            }
            txtMatriz.Text = txtMatriz.Text + "\r\n";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Almacenar suma de cada fila de una matriz en un vector en C# forms

Solo necesitas crear el arreglo e ir sumando cada vez que vayas a recorrer una columna:

```
int R, C;
int[,] N;
Random aleatorio = new Random();
N= new int [4,5];

int[] arr = new int[4];//Aquí almacenamos la suma total de cada fila..

for (R=0;R <4; R++)
{
    for (C=0; C<5;C++)
    {
        N[R, C] = aleatorio.Next(-100, 100);
        txtMatriz.Text = txtMatriz.Text + N[R, C] + "\t";
        arr[i] += N[R,C];
    }
    txtMatriz.Text = txtMatriz.Text + "\r\n";
}
```

Para imprimirlo en un `textBox` sería de esta forma:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    txtVector.Text  = txtVector.Text + arr[i] + "\n";
```